# Groovy find the most current version of a file with recursive directory search

Tags: java, groovy

I am a Groovy novice.  I would like to be able to find the most current version of a supplied file.   I have a starting folder and need to recursively search for that file across all subordinate folders.   The same file name can be in multiple folders and my goal is to grab the most current version.  I think the key is the eachDirRecurse and eachFileMatch but not quite sure how to put them all together to get the most current version of the file.

Comment: And how do you recognize a version of that file?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want to compare the last modified date of the files with the same name: you use `eachFileRecurse` to iterate all files.  then filter for the same in question.  next compare for "current".  e.g.:

```
// create some test files named `t` in `t[123]` dirs
['t3','t1','t2'].each{
    (it as File).with{
        new AntBuilder().delete(dir:it) // get rid of existing
        mkdir() // create new one
    }
    new File("$it/t").write "t" // write text file
    Thread.sleep(1000) // sleep to have different modification times
}

def hit // the found "current"
def last // the highest "current"
new File(".").eachFileRecurse{
    if (it.name=='t') { // check for your filename here
        def l = it.lastModified() // your comparsion for "current"; just java API in this case
        if (last<l) {
            last = l
            hit = it
        }
    }
}

assert hit==new File("./t2/t")
```